# Xamarin.Forms iOS App Crashes due to SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash

I recently got a lot of App crashes due to the error: SIGABRT: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The problem happens in iOS devices. I googled around, but could not find root cause.  One of thoughts is that it can happen when the app is put to background while a network request is in progress, and then when the app is restored to foreground, it crashes. However, I can never reproduce the issue manually.  I am attaching the stack traces here for your reference. Hope someone here has an idea about the root cause of this issue.

Development environment:

1. Xamarin.iOS v14.6.0.15 (Build date: 2020-11-16)
2. Xcode version: 12.2

> CFNetworkHandler.HandleHasBytesAvailableEvent (System.Object sender,
> CoreFoundation.CFStream+StreamEventArgs e)
>
> CFStream.OnHasBytesAvailableEvent
> (CoreFoundation.CFStream+StreamEventArgs args)
>
> CFStream.OnCallback (CoreFoundation.CFStreamEventType type)
>
> CFStream.OnCallback (System.IntPtr s, System.nint type, System.IntPtr
> info)
>
> (wrapper native-to-managed)
> CoreFoundation.CFStream.OnCallback(intptr,System.nint,intptr)
>
> (wrapper managed-to-native)
> UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>
> UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal,
> System.IntPtr delegate)
>
> UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String
> principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
>
> Application.Main (System.String[] args)
>
> (wrapper managed-to-native)
> UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>
> UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal,
> System.IntPtr delegate)
>
> UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String
> principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
>
> Application.Main (System.String[] args)

Comment: The stack trace you shared does not help much and can you share more from iOS logs(Tools -> iOS -> Device logs)?

Comment: Thanks Jack for the quick reply! Unfortunately, I am not able to get the iOS logs. Those crashes are from some of the clients and they got automatically reported to the app center. The only log that I can get is the information above. As I mentioned above, I am not able to reproduce it manually either.

Comment: Have you tried [iOS Symbolication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/ios-symbolication#:~:text=Log%20into%20App%20Center%20and,will%20be%20symbolicated%20for%20you.) in AppCenter. We can't get much useful info from the stack trace you shared.